# Migrating a Github repository with all the commit history to Perforce

Tags: git, migration, perforce

The title is self explanatory, how can i migrate a github repository with commit history to Perforce. Thanks.

Comment: This question is about migrating a repository from one platform to another, how is this "enthusiast" or an End user question? As a system administrator it is my duty to ensure we do not loose information when we migrate the platform.

Comment: http://www.perforce.com/downloads/git-fusion

Answer (score 2):

Perforce knows Git-SCM, so it should theoretically be as simple as creating a new remote, and pushing with the `-a` flag.

A git repository is simply a git repository, regardless of where it is hosted at, in general.  (There are exceptions, such as Heroku, and Perforce may be one of those exceptions.)

If this does not work... what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have been researching how to do this, Perforce has a tool/add on called Git fusion, but that's more aligned with using both platforms at the same time (AFAIK). The other tool i found ( Tailor -- http://darcs.net/RelatedSoftware/Tailor ) only supports Perforce as a source for migration, not as a target. Still trying to look for a way to keep the history. Mind you, the history is non linear, which apparently is a factor in the migration.